# How to remove a line under number chapter in classicthesis?

Tags: classicthesis

I've been working on a thesis with TeXShop for three years now and I'm finalizing my writing. I'm trying to change my `classicthesis` template a litte bit. I would like to remove the line under the number chapter. Indeed, I put a `minitoc` in front of each chapter and therefore, there are three lines in the beginning of the page. Can someone tell me how to remove that line?

This is the code of my preamble :

```
% book example for classicthesis.sty
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,footinclude=true,headinclude=true]{scrbook} % KOMA-Script book
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}     
\usepackage[applemac]{inputenc}    
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage{setspace} 
\usepackage{hyperref} 
\usepackage[tight,french]{minitoc}
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[parts,pdfspacing,dottedtoc,eulerchapternumbers]{../classicthesis} % ,manychapters
%\usepackage[osf]{libertine}
\usepackage[left=3.5cm,right=3.5cm,top=3cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\FrenchFootnotes
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{lineno}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\thepart}{\Roman{part}}}
\frontmatter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\def\ptctitle{Table}
\def\mtctitle{Table}
\def\stctitle{Table}
\setlength{\mtcindent}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\mtifont}{\normalsize\scshape\lsstyle}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%modifie la taille des numéros de chapitres%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\ifthenelse{\boolean{@eulerchapternumbers}}% font for the chapter numbers
    {\newcommand\mychapterNumber{\fontencoding{U}\fontfamily{eur}\fontseries{b}\fontsize{28}{29}\selectfont}}%
    {\newcommand\mychapterNumber{\fontencoding{T1}\fontfamily{pplj}\fontsize{25}{26}\selectfont}}

\ifthenelse{\boolean{@linedheaders}}%
    {%
    \titleformat{\chapter}[block]%
        {\relax}{\titlerule\vspace*{.9\baselineskip}\\\raggedleft{\color{halfgray}\mychapterNumber\thechapter}}{1.2em}%
        {\raggedright\spacedallcaps}[\normalsize\vspace*{.8\baselineskip}\titlerule]%
    }{%
    \titleformat{\chapter}[block]%
        {\relax}{{\color{halfgray}\mychapterNumber\thechapter}}{1.2em}%
        {\raggedright\spacedallcaps}[\normalsize\vspace*{.8\baselineskip}\titlerule]%
    }
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\begin{document}
%   \pagestyle{scrheadings}
%   \manualmark
%   \markboth{\spacedlowsmallcaps{\contentsname}}{\spacedlowsmallcaps{\contentsname}}




\dominitoc
\tableofcontents



\pagestyle{scrheadings}

\end{document}
```

For the moment, I have a line under the title of my chapter. Here is a part of a screenshot of a chapter:

[image]

And I would like to remove that line :

[image]

Thanks for your help ! Your suggestions work :
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. In order to get the best possible help around here, it is good practice to add a [MWE (minimal working example)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) that shows in a concise way what you have so far. It would also be helpful if you were able to describe in more detail the output you get right now and the output you hope to achieve.

Comment: OK. This is the code of my preamble :

Comment: Unfortunately, your MWE is in the `document`-part quite a bit too minimal, could you flesh it out a bit, so we can actually see (chapters, sections, ...) and the minitoc? You could make your MWE more concise by getting rid of some of the packages (`amsthm`, `apacite`, ...) that have no bearing on the issue at hand.

Comment: In the meantime, you can play around with the code after `\boolean{@linedheaders}`: There are some `\titlerule`s there, see if you like the result better, if you get rid of any of them.

Comment: It works. I removed the two following lines : [\normalsize\vspace*{.8\baselineskip}\titlerule]%

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is too localized.